# UnityWebGL and Github LFS not working on server

Tags: unity-game-engine, ubuntu, github, nginx, webgl

I have a very specific problem, I have a nextjs project, with a unity build in the public folder. When the build is less than 100 MBs i can be pushed to GitHub normally. From there I pull it to my ubuntu server and run docker. The project serves normally, and the webgl build shows normally. The problem is when the file is greater than 100 MBs, i can not push it to GitHub and need to use GitHub lfs. When i use github lfs, multiple problems arise, the first is that even though the build and project work fine locally, and webgl renders correctly, when i pull it on the server and vercel, both times the render fails with console errors unable to parse the compression. However locally it is parsed normally. I retried without LFS locally since i can't push it to github and the build works fine. I need help in either finding a solution with github LFS, or another way of copying the build folders to the ubuntu server and from there moving them to the public file.

I tried different compressions .gz .br .unityweb, the best one was .unityweb with a gz compression, however all of them work locally. We can make sure that the enviroment is set up perfectly because we tried different builds and as soon as we remove the LFS and the ability to pull and push to github normally without github LFS the render and the build shows fine on the server